# Is it possible to combine MySQL queries to multiple tables into a single query based on the results from one of the queries?

Tags: mysql

The `$userid` of the currently logged in user is all the is currently available in the PHP code. I want to run a query against the mysql tables to return all of the status updates for myself and for friends ordered by `createddate DESC`.

MySQL Sample database tables:

[statusupdates]

```
statusupdateid int(8)  
ownerid int(8)
message varchar(250)
createddate datetime
```

[friends]

```
friendid int(8)
requestfrom int(8)
requestto int(8)
daterequested datetime
dateupdated datetime
status varchar(1)
```

Question: Can I perform a single string query that returns each `statusupdates.userid` and the `statusupdates.message` ordered by `statusupdates.createddate DESC`?

Or do I have to run a query for each `friends` record where the `$userid` is in either the `friends.requestfrom` or `friends.requestto` then, run another query for alternate `friends.requestfrom` or `friends.requestto` (the one that doesn't include `$userid`), then sort all of the results by `statusupdate.createddate` and then get the `statusupdates.message`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at MySQL Joins.

I think this may do something like what you're after, but it will almost definitely need debugging!

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.ownerid, s.message 
FROM statusupdates s 
LEFT JOIN friends f ON ($userid = f.requestfrom) 
LEFT JOIN friends f ON ($userid = f.requestto)
ORDER BY s.createddate;
```

Comment: I searched and found the page http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp so I know understand that I can essentially link 2 columns in 2 tables but I am unsure how to do it with 2 columns in the "friends" table potentially matching "statusupdates.ownerid"

Comment: Sorry I was trying to refer to the statusupdates table and the ownerid (but I wrote userid by accident)

Comment: I'll pin something together. :)

Comment: There's an edit. Sorry - I'm not the greatest SQL writer, it probably won't work for you first time!

Comment: Had to change f on second LEFT JOIN as it said f was not unique. But it worked I believe! I got the result I expected but still would like to test it in more complex situations. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I used g instead of f - figured it was just a unique letter and doesn't need to be any specific character.

Comment: Just be aware that this creates duplicate rows - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85ea0/6

Comment: SystemX17 - to clarify, the 'f' is like a variable name, to represent the table. So it can be any unique letter, or string. 
@Sean - Thanks! If you don't want these duplicates SystemX17 - add 'DISTINCT' after SELECT, as edited in above.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but should work or at least get you in the right direction.

You could use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) where you get a list of `userid`s from a sub query. That subquery does a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) on 2 queries - 1st to get the `requestfrom` `userid`s, and 2nd to get the `requestto` `userids`. Finally we add an `OR` to include the current `userid.`

also, I assume that you also want to filter out where `status = 1`, as you don't want updates from those who have not confirmed friendships

```
SELECT s.ownerid, s.message 
FROM statusupdates s 
WHERE s.ownerid IN (
                   SELECT f1.requestfrom
                   FROM friends f1
                   WHERE f1.requestto = $userid
                   AND f1.status = 1

                   UNION

                   SELECT f2.requestto
                   FROM friends f2
                   WHERE f2.requestfrom = $userid
                   AND f2.status = 1
                   )
OR s.ownerid = $userid
ORDER BY s.createddate DESC
```

take a look at this sqlFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85ea0/3

Comment: I have edited my answer with a way to filter out to only `status = 1` friends, and a sqlFiddle example.

Comment: This also works after testing. I wish I could mark 2 answers as correct as both the responses work, but just use a different method. Thank you for your time. It is much appreciated.